# How to return the header by value in a PivotTable

Tags: excel, excel-formula, match, pivot-table, worksheet-function

I have a PivotTable like this:

```
Sum of Gf_Amount |  Column Labels               
                 |  2015    |        |        |         | Grand Total
Row Labels       |  17-Mar  | 18-Mar | 19-Mar | 20-Mar  |
3601             |  20      | 20     |        |         | 40
10386            |  35      |        |        |         | 35
76301            |  5       |        |        |         | 5
80941            |          |        |        | 10      | 10     
205738           |          |        | 5      |         | 5
219576           |          |  15    |        |         | 15
Grand Total      |  60      | 35     | 5      | 10      | 110
```

What I want do is find the last non-empty column and return the date according to the value. For example: for ID `3601` the result should be `2015 18-Mar`.

Currently I know how to find the last non-empty column by using `=LOOKUP(9.99E+307,B6:E6)`. For ID `3601` it gives me `20` which is correct. However when I use:

```
=INDEX($B$5:$E$5,MATCH(LOOKUP(9.99E+307,B6:E6),B6:E6,0))
```

to find the header, it gives me `17-Mar` which is the corresponding header for the *first* `20`. Besides, the formula I wrote can't even give me the year.

Can anyone help me out so I can find the date and year? (It doesn't have to be in PivotTable. You can copy and paste it in a normal table.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that your column labels are date indices formatted as `dd-mmm` so there is no need to find the `2015` that is displayed hence:

```
 =INDEX($5:$5,MATCH(1E+100,A6:E6))
```

formatted as say `dd-mmm-yyyy` and presumably copied down may suit.

---

It is a peculiarity (perhaps never really intended) of the [MATCH](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MATCH-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca) function that, without the optional argument, where it can’t find a match in a list it returns the index of the last entry in the list – very useful, as here, at times! So all the “big number” (there are lots of versions of it – for example the one you used `9.99E+307`) does is feed MATCH a number so large it is never likely to find it (to force selection of the last entry).

I like `1E+100`, a [googol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Googol), as short and easy to remember, and for its ‘derivation’. `9.99E+307` is theoretically better as closer to the largest number Excel can handle: 
9.99999999999999E+307
but

10,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000

for me is big enough – I don’t expect ever to want to work with a number bigger than that and smaller than or equal to 9.99E+307.

Comment: Great! Thanks. I just want to know how this works. Why we use 1E+100?