# Understanding a lookup formula used to calculate balances based on transactions

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, vlookup, lookup

Below I was given the following formula to lookup the last transaction in an account (there is a total of 4 accounts) and calculate its current balance based on the transaction of the current row (in this case row 1075). `$E$2:$E1074` is the range for the varrying accounts. `$F$2:$F1074` is the range of balances associated with each of those accounts. `$C1075` is the current transaction we are looking at on row 1075. The error is included in the case that the account in column E does no match an other account in column E and therefore is a new account and the first transaction for that account. **This code works.**

```
=IFERROR(LOOKUP(2,1/($E$2:$E1074=$E1075),$F$2:$F1074)-$C1075,-$C1075)
```

I have experience with vlookup and hlookup but I don't understand the first two sections of this `lookup` function. specifically the `2` and the `1/($E$2:$E1074=$E1075)`. I'm not sure what these two values calculate and output to give the desired result. Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: It seems to be a formula to retrieve the value from column F associated with the last value in column E that matches E1075 (and subtracts C1075 from that value).

Comment: Yes that is true and I understand that the formula works to do this I just don't understand why. I am hoping to replicate something similar but I am unsure why there is a 1 divided by the range in column E. It seems like you should just have the rang in column E without the `1/`

Comment: 'cause you are looking for the value in column F that is associated with the **last** instance where $E$2:$E1074=$E1075 (which will equal zero for false and **1** for true). Since there are no twos in that array of comparisons, it will give you the last **1** (i.e. the last match).

Comment: Have you made the ranges smaller (4-6 rows) and worked through Formulas, Formula Auditing, Evaluate Formula?

Comment: I see. so you will either get an error (1/0 or **no match**) or a value (1/1 or **match**) but the last thing I don't understand is the `2` for the lookup value. your range is either going to be a 1 or an error. there will be no 2's

Comment: Right, so its going to get the **last** **1**, not the first **1**. Note that LOOKUP does not have a fourth parameter like VLOOKUP (or a third parameter like MATCH). IOW, if you are looking up **2** and the highest actual number is **1** then you will get the **last 1**.

Comment: I don't understand how it makes sense to have a **lookup value of 2** here though.

I feel like I am so close to understanding. so the parameters for VLOOKUP are (lookup value, lookup array, col index, rangelookup) where the lookup value is searched for in the lookup array. Is in not the same for LOOKUP where the parameters are  (**lookup value**, lookup vector, result vector)

Answer (score 0):

Why `2` is for much the same reason as why a "big number" or "big text" (say `zzz`) can be useful in a MATCH function (that I tried to explain [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29665885/1505120)). Here any number larger than `1` would serve since the objective is to look for what does *not* exist in order to make the search continue through to the last entry. Returning that last entry, rather than an error for "Not found" *may* not have been intended - but can be very useful.